Proving Scripture by Scripture (Acts. 17:11), what Old Testament reference validates Paul's statement in Titus 1:2?
Titus 1:2 KJV:  "In hope of eternal life, which God, that cannot lie, promised before the world began."
My question is: where in other Scripture, mainly Old Testament Scripture (as opposed to other Scripture of Paul), does it specifically say that God made this promise "before the world began?"

Paul had been deeply schooled in reading, memorizing, and understanding the ancient Hebrew scriptures, being "taught at the feet of Gamaliel" (Acts 22:3). All that before he had his vision of the risen Christ, leading to his conversion to faith in Christ. Thereafter, everything quickly fell into place, once Christ was given his proper place.
Due to Paul's meticulous explanations about Christ being, for example, the everlasting Son of God, showing his theology based on those Hebrew scriptures, his Christian understanding of the opening chapters of Genesis would provide a basis for saying what he said in Titus 1:2.
Paul would know, and believe, the promise God made to Adam and Eve at the point when they had just come under the condemnation of sin and death. After cursing the serpent, God said this to the serpent:

"And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy
seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his
heel" Genesis 3:15 K.J.V.

This might well be said to be the first prophecy in the Bible; pointing to deliverance from condemnation to sin and death - to overcoming the hopelessness of their lost estate via one who would deal with all that brought in the devastation of sin and death. Note that this one is called "he" - and his symbolic 'heel' would be bruised but he would not be overcome or destroyed. On the contrary, he would overcome and destroy the serpent and his 'seed'.
When Paul's theology is examined, he often refers to the first Adam, and the last Adam - Christ. He often provides the Hebraic theology for showing the triumph unto life everlasting. This is the Christian's hope. And that Paul says God gave this sure promise "before the world began" indicates his understanding that, for God to instantly give that promise before the couple were put out of Eden shows God was not "caught on the hop"; God knew full well what he would need to do to keep his purpose in creation on track for its glorious outcome:

"Nevertheless we, according to his promise, look for new heavens
and a new earth, wherein dwelleth righteousness." K.J.V. emphasis mine

This will be the fulfilment of the promise, when God brings in the new creation and the new humanity, in Christ. Therefore the Bible speaks of the 'woman' bringing forth a man-child, caught away to God in heaven, to defeat the attempts of the serpent (there called the great red dragon, 'that old serpent', called the devil and Satan - Revelation chapter 12 which details the outworking of the promise given in Genesis 3:15).
Then, at the end of that prophetic book, the Tree of Life appears once more, but this time in Heaven. Until then, the way to it, and the everlasting life it gives, has been debarred by God's flaming sword. That appeared in Eden, to prevent the sinning couple from partaking of it and so living forever.  But because God knows the end from the beginning (Mat.28:20, Isaiah 46:10), he declared his eternal purposes back in Eden, and Paul then discovered the amazing extent of God's foreknowledge, and his eternal purposes that cannot be thwarted by anyone or anything. First stated to the first humanity in Eden. Fulfilled in the last Adam who 'owns' the second humanity, in Christ.
The world had only just begun when God showed he had decided to proceed with a material creation despite knowing what Satan would do. And he already knew how he would overcome all that to restore to perfection the corruption brought in by sin and death. He declared that glorious hope in his glorious promises, as recorded in Genesis 3:14, but every last, minute detail of that promise had to be determined by God before creation began; which is what the rest of the entire Bible demonstrates. And didn't Paul know it!

So, in effect, you are saying that a perfect God knew before He created Adam and Eve that they were not going to obey Him.

the fulfilment of the promise, when God brings in the new creation and the new humanity, in Christ. // God knows the end from the beginning  Music to my ears and up-voted +1.

Answer
The answer is given in the very next verse itself.

“on hope of eternal life which the God who does not lie promised
before the eternal times, BUT REVEALED in its own times in a
proclamation of His Word” (Titus 1:2-3).

Explanation
So, we see that God made the promise to Himself (i.e., He planned it) before the eternal times, that is, to scientifically speak, ‘before time began’.
But this promise was revealed later, that is, again to use the scientific jargon, ‘after time began’, in the due time, especially when He started to proclaim His Word through Moses and the prophets.
Do we see any mention of such promise?
Yes.

“It is like the dew from Mount Hermon, falling on Zion's mountains,
where the LORD has promised to bless his people with LIFE
forevermore.” (Psalms 133:3).

Zion is the representative figure of Jerusalem that is the capital of the Promised Land. So God made His promise of eternal life to His people in the mountains near Jerusalem.
Again, do we see any such incident in the Old Testament (which the OP insists to find out)?
Yes.

“I call Heaven and earth to witness against you today that I have set
before you LIFE and death, the blessing and the curse.
Therefore, choose LIFE, that you may LIVE, you and your seed”
(Deut 30:19).

Oh, where are the mountains of Zion involved here?

“And it shall be when Jehovah your God shall bring you into the land
(of Zion) to which you go to possess it, that you shall set the
blessing on Mount Gerizim, and the curse on Mount Ebal” (Deut
11:29).

There it is.
God gave a promise and a choice to Israel.
[The details of how to do it are given in Deuteronomy 27:12-26. The actual thing took place in Joshua 8:30-35.]
Same Promise to Adam & Eve
The same God has given the same promise to the first human beings also:

“And out of the ground Jehovah God made to spring up every tree that
is pleasant to the sight, and good for food. The Tree of LIFE
(life eternal) was also in the middle of the garden; also the Tree of
the Knowledge of Good and Evil (death)” (Gen 2:9).

The same God gave the same choice to them too.

“And Jehovah God commanded the man, saying, Eating you may eat of
every tree in the garden; but of the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and
Evil you may not eat, for in the day that you eat of it, dying you
shall die” (Gen 2:16-17).

Adam and Eve could eat from every tree including the “Tree of LIFE” which was a blessing. The only prohibited tree was the tree of curse. But unfortunately, human history took a cursed turn.
But God’s promise is open still to human beings. God renews it through Prophet Jeremiah:

“And you shall say to this people, So says Jehovah, Behold, I set
before you the way of LIFE and the way of death” (Jer 21:8).

Conclusion
So God planned (promised Himself) the eternal life for humans before time began but He revealed it later when He started to write down His Word through His prophets.
We see the promise right from the Garden of Eden and onwards continuing in the New Testament through the Gospel of Jesus Christ.

The answer you gave, that it was revealed in the next verse, are Paul’s own words, so that don’t give me a clue whether this new revelation of foreknowledge  is truth, because his own words alone wouldn't prove it.  I can’t see where Jesus would reveal a new concept to him and not to His own disciples unless that concept was meant to be only used with the Gentiles; something like good cop-bad cop in interrogation, where Jesus’ disciples are the good cops and Paul is the bad cop.  Even in that situation, the good cops would know of it, so where in their Scriptures is it revealed?

You first wanted to prove Scripture with Scripture, especially OT. So I gave you Psalms 133:3, Deuteronomy, Genesis and Jeremiah references to prove when God revealed the promises to Israel as Paul stated in Titus 1:3. Now you complain that Jesus revealed to Paul but not to other apostles. This is simply untrue. Peter talks the same thing: “indeed having been foreknown before the foundation of the world, but revealed in the last times because of you” (1 Pet 1:20).

Besides, Paul also learned things initially from Peter (Gal 1:18). Later, he always made sure that he was going in the right direction by submitting his gospel preaching before Peter, John and James (Gal 2:2). I believe there is nothing Paul knows that Peter doesn't know.

Yes, I did want another verse, either in the OT or another person's writings in the NT which would prove the statement Paul made.  None of the ones you listed in the OT proved to me whether God had established the salvation plan before the world began, or when the sin first occurred and was recorded.  Preacher Marcus yesterday found the one you refer to in Peter, which answered my question.  And I agree, there is nothing Paul knows that Peter doesn't know about the subject.  Thanks for your efforts.

Thanks Joanne. A +1 for you.

My literal translation of Titus 1:2 reads:

in hope of life eternal, which God, who cannot lie, promised before
time eternal

Note the word "eternal", αἰώνιος, can mean "eternal" or "the worlds as a spatial concept" (BDAG), but we will not consider this here.
Before answering this question let me observe that if God promised something before the "time eternal", that promise cannot be found in Scripture because that was well before the any Scripture was written!
Ellicott says this nicely when he observes:

Promised before the world began.—More accurately rendered, from eternal ages. The promise of eternal life was the result of a divine
purpose fixed from eternity.

Indeed, Paul says in 1 Tim 1:9 -

He has saved us and called us to a holy life—not because of anything
we have done but because of his own purpose and grace. This grace was
given us in Christ Jesus before the beginning of time,

However, first time this promise of salvation is recorded in Scripture is famously found in Gen 3:15 -

And I will put enmity between you and the woman, and between your
offspring and hers; he will crush your head, and you will strike his
heel.”

Benson also succinctly observes in his comments about Titus 1:2 alluding to Gen 3:15 -

That this included a promise of eternal life to all believers has
frequently been shown.

This promise of the Great messiah to come was repeated many times in Scripture beginning with Abraham who was promised that:

Gen 12:3 - I will bless those who bless you, and whoever curses you I
will curse; and all peoples on earth will be blessed through you.”
See also Gen 18:18, 22;18, Gal 3:8, etc.


I observed what Ellicott did. You could translate it, "before time."

@PerryWebb - my literal translation would be: "in hope of life eternal, which God, who cannot lie, promise before time eternal."

These are all good references, but I don't see where any of them establish the truth of Paul's statement.  My problem with it is that it looks as if Paul is "adding to God's Word" (Deut. 4:1, 2; Rev. 22:18).
II Tim. 1:9 is also Paul's own words, so that wouldn't meet the test of being the testimony of two men for truth (John 8:17).
Gen. 12:3 shown to be God's first promise along with a judgment was "after the world began," and could have been an in-the-moment decision, so that don't verify it.  So would be any future promises.

@Joanne - Paul adding to God's word - of course he did - he contributed half the NT as an inspired prophet of God.  What is the problem?  Paul simply reports that Jesus and the Father made a "deal" before there was even a sinner about the plan of salvation "before time eternal."

That sounds pretty far-fetched to me that such a deal would be made before He even created the world.  Are you saying that He then created the world knowing He would be creating sinners that His Son would need to die for?

@Joanne - that is what the NT says repeatedly: Eph 1;4, Rev 13:8, Matt 25:34, etc.

@Dottard - Your quotes listed seem to be coming from two different schools of thought, which can be opposed to each other.  In Eph, 1:4 Paul is talking about predestination, where God has foreordained every event in history.  Matt, 25:34 Jesus’ teaching here is about free-will— a person’s choice to do either good or bad to others.  Rev. 13:8 sounds to me like a free-will choice.

@Joanne - your points are debatable.  I suggest you do a simple search (either here or on Bublehub) of "foundation of the world".

@Dottard - Is that Biblehub?  I’ll do that when I get some time. Thanks.

@PreacherMarcus - Does it say anywhere else in the Bible that God set that in motion "before creation," or is that Paul's own concept?

@PreacherMarcus - Thank you for your meticulous search of Scripture and providing an answer to my question. The one verse that was most convincing to me is I Peter 1:20 of which my KJV records:  "Who verily was 'foreordained' before the foundation of the world, but was manifest in these last times for you."  (My emphasis.)  Peter sure redeemed himself and Jesus knew and foretold it (Matt. 16:18).

Here is a different translation of the same verse to help get a grasp on  something God promised before the ages commenced.

in hope of the Life of the Ages which God, who is never false to His word, promised before the commencement of the Ages.

There are things that Paul wrote about that you will never find in the Old Testament.  That is because God kept some things  secret until He revealed them through the apostle Paul, they were mysteries hidden in God, not in the scriptures.

we speak the hidden wisdom of God in a secret, that God foreordained BEFORE the AGES to our glory, which no one of the rulers of this age did know, for if they had known, the Lord of the glory they would not have crucified; 1: Corinthians 2:7

So it looks like God kept some thing secret otherwise  the Lord of glory may not have been crucified.

Now to Him who is able to strengthen you by my gospel and by the proclamation of Jesus Christ, according to the revelation of the mystery concealed for ages past
Roman's 16:25

This particular mystery had been concealed in the past ages.  It never showed up in the old Testament.

I became its servant by the commission God gave me to fully proclaim to you the word of God, the mystery that was hidden for ages and generations but is now revealed to His saints.
Colossians 1:26


To proclaim good news—the untraceable riches of the Christ, and  to cause all to see what [is] the fellowship of the secret that has been hid from the ages in God, who created all things by Jesus Christ, that there might be made known now to the principalities and the authorities in the heavenly [places], through the Assembly, the manifold wisdom of God, according to the purpose of the ages, which He made in Christ Jesus our Lord.  Ephesians 3:8-12

In verse eight above, we see there are some things that are untraceable.
◄ 421. anexichniastos ►

Strong's Exhaustive Concordance
past finding out; unsearchable.
From a (as a negative particle) and a presumed derivative of a compound of ekand a derivative of ichnos; not tracked out, i.e. (by implication) untraceable -- past finding out; unsearchable.
see GREEK a

The OP brought up
Acts 17:11 where the people examined the Scriptures to see if Paul's message was in accord with the Old Testament scriptures. They did not rely on Jewish tradition and teaching of the elders but studied scriptures themselves.  Paul had been showing them from scriptures that Christ must suffer and rise from among the dead and that this one is Christ, the Jesus who he was announcing to them.

explaining and proving that it was necessary for the Christ to suffer and to rise from the dead, and saying, “This Jesus, whom I proclaim to you, is the Christ.” Acts 17:3

The apostle Paul received revelations from the ascended glorified Christ and He showed him things that had never been seen, written or revealed before.

I received my message from no human source, and no one taught me. Instead, I received it by direct revelation from Jesus Christ. Galatians 1:12

Paul received revelations in installments and they went from glory to glory.

Acts 26:15 And I said, Who art thou, Lord? And he said, I am Jesus whom thou persecutest. 16 But rise, and stand upon thy feet: for I have appeared unto thee for this purpose, to make thee a minister and a witness both of these things which thou hast seen, and of those things in the which I will appear unto thee;

In conclusion Paul use many Old Testament scriptures to verify who Christ was.  He also was given revelations that are untraceable that  you could never find in the Old Testament.

I have no issue with Paul teaching Christ, what I am trying to prove is this new revelation of foreknowledge of Paul’s, which could cancel out free will.  I don’t see where Jesus’ own disciples were teaching that. And what other Scriptures did the Bereans have those days than those from the Old Testament (Acts 17:11)?

@ JoAnne thanks for your questions. God does determines things before hand as seen throughout scripture.  Even Jesus told His disciples they did not choose him, but He chose them.  The apostle Paul was also chosen by God, even against his "free will." It was through the will of God that he became an apostle as Colossians 1:1 says.  God separated him and moved him on.  Later Israel had been temporarily set aside because of their unbelief, then some of God's secrets and purposes are being revealed through the Apostle to the Gentiles. As I said in my post, you won't find them in the OT.

One just needs to take them by faith that they to are the word of God even as Titus 1:2 says that Paul, a servant of God and an apostle of Jesus Christ, according to the faith of the elect of God and the knowledge of the truth.

@Joann. Here are a couple other scripture that confirms Grace being given before the ages, (not eternity's) began.2:Timothy 1-9 who saved us and called us to a holy calling, not because of our works but because of his own purpose and grace, which he gave us in Christ Jesus before the ages began. God calls people according to His purpose which is for a new administration in the heavenly realm in the coming ages to head up the universe in the heavens and on the earth in Christ in whom our lot is cast. Eph. 1:10

@Sherrie - Those two references are both Paul's words.  I was trying to get a testimony from another source.  Preacher Marcus found one which was convincing to me.  Thanks.

@Joanne I am glad Marcus found one that was convincing to you.  You never know with a multitude of answers what will satisfy a question that's being asked and it's wonderful when one gets an answer that helps.

Young's translates this as:

upon hope of life age-during, which God, who doth not lie, did promise before times of ages, (Titus 1:2, YLT)

There is an Hebraic concept in the phrase "before the world began" or "before the foundation of the world" which does not translate literally in the English.  That phrase to the Jews meant before the Law was given.  Their world, their culture, their beliefs were centered in the Law thereby their existence was counted from their Exodus from Egypt and the giving of the Law at Mt. Sinai.
From Clarke's Commentary at Titus 1:2:

Which God, that cannot lie, promised — We have often seen that the phrase, the foundation of the world, means the Jewish economy, and, before the foundation of the world, the times antecedent to the giving of the law. This is evidently the meaning here. See 2 Timothy 1:9-11.


Supposing the word αιωνιων in this verse to signify eternal, says Dr. Macknight, the literal translation of προ χρονων αιωνιων would be, before eternal times; but that being a contradiction in terms, our translators, contrary to the propriety of the Greek language, have rendered it before the world began, as Mr. Locke observes on Romans 16:25. The true literal translation is before the secular times, referring us to the Jewish jubilees, by which times were computed among the Hebrews, as among the Gentiles they were computed by generations of men. Hence, Colossians 1:26, The mystery which was kept hid απο των αιωνων και απο των γενεων, from the ages and from the generations, signifies the mystery which was kept hid from the Jews and from the Gentiles.  Source: Clarke's

In addition to the prophesy of Christ in Gen. 3:15, we have the promise of the savior Yeshua to Abraham:

and God saith unto Abraham, `Let it not be wrong in thine eyes because of the youth, and because of thy handmaid: all that Sarah saith unto thee -- hearken to her voice, for in Isaac is a seed called to thee.  (Gen. 21:12, YLT)


that blessing I bless thee, and multiplying I multiply thy seed as stars of the heavens, and as sand which [is] on the sea-shore; and thy seed doth possess the gate of his enemies; (Gen. 22:17, YLT)   also


The sceptre turneth not aside from Judah, And a lawgiver from between his feet, Till his Seed come; And his [is] the obedience of peoples.  (Gen. 49:10, YLT)

Summed up in Gal. 3:16,

and to Abraham were the promises spoken, and to his seed; He doth not say, And to seeds,' as of many, but as of one, And to thy seed,' which is Christ; (YLT)


Are you saying that what Paul meant by his phrase "before the world began," is he meant "before the Law was given?"

That is the sense that Clarke's commentary states.  It is a Jewish concept, just as they called the temple "heaven and earth."  When was the first temple established?  Under the Mosaic law, which God called "heaven and earth" in Deu. 4:26 & 31.26.  Heaven and earth then was another creation, the world of the Mosaic covenant.

Does not God wish us to share His eternal Kingdom with us? Yes, He wishes that, and that is the purpose why He sent His only-begotten, co-eternal God-Son to us, who having become man, suffered and died on cross, and has risen from dead.
Now, was this purpose not purposed by Him before He created the world? Impossible! So, that is what Paul says. He does not refer to any specific quote from the Holy Scriptures, but to something greater and more principal: a theological common sense.

So, it looks to me like you are saying that Paul, not referring to any specific quote from the Holy Scriptures, had a greater and more principled theological common sense than the Saviour Jesus Christ who stood up to read the Scriptures, quoted from them, taught His disciples of them, lived and died by them; and the Old Testament was His only Bible.

@Joanne Yes, the Lord both quoted OT and  a l s o  said things not written anywhere; so does Paul, and so should do any truth-respecting and self-respecting man.

How then do you distinguish truth from error?

In addition to my comment above:  How then do you distinguish truth from error, Jesus, when contending with the Devil, quoted Scripture (Matt. 4:1-11).

@Joanne The Lord quoted Scripture, yes, but He also said many totally novel things, without reference to the Scripture. That we, humans, move in God and are His offsprings was taken by Paul from pagan Aratus (Acts 17:28), and the latter took it from common sense and reason. Bible does not only teach the common sense and reason, but also presupposes them, for unless you possess common sense, reading of the Bible will do no good to you, whereas common sense is always beneficial, with or without Bible.

Yes, common sense is great for some things, and it would be nice if everyone had it; however, common sense will only get you so far.  I found common sense didn't answer why Job, who was perfect in God's sight, along with His own Son, had to suffer so terribly.  "For who hath known the mind of the Lord?  or who hath been his counsellor?" (Rom. 11:34)

@Joanne That God wanted us to share eternity with Him even before He created the universe is a plain logic and common sense, a theological truism, and one does not need any reference to a concrete Biblical verse to corroborate it. That’s why Paul just says it, casually, as is meet.

That wasn't the question.  If I had given it more thought, I would have figured out, that with the Devil's existence, He sure would need a plan ahead of time to save His creation.  His creation were no match for the Devil's wiles.  Scripture alone was the tactic Jesus used when contending with him in Matt. 4:11, and is a very good example for us.

@Joanne Job, whom you love so much, was not even a Jew and knew not a single sentence from any Scripture. Yes, Lord contended with devil using Scriptures because devil used Scriptures, but Lord is not fettered by Scriptures and even changes them at will (“Moses said so, but I say so…”). Lord does not want us to be slaves of any text, but to live in Spirit and Truth. That God knows all beforehand and wishes good and salvation to all, well, one has not to be a doctor of theology to know this, for it is self-evident and one does not need to search such a truism in Scriptures

There are different "opinions" whether Job was Jewish or not; however he worshipped the same God and he's mentioned in the Jewish Scriptures:  Ezekial 14:20 and James 5:11.  It doesn't matter so much what I think of him, but more importantly what God thought of him (Job 1:8).  Is it just an internal revelation from common sense that Job didn't know any Scripture?  The Lord supported Moses words (Matthew 5); however He gave them a more deeper meaning.  I suppose a person can "prove truth" other ways than Scripture, but experience is sometimes a hard lesson.

@Joanne Yes, exactly! Job did not read any Scripture, neither Noah did, nor Melchizedek, nor Homer, nor Hesiod, nor Plato or Sophocles, but they said and did things that reached realm of divine truth and dignity, having become a common heritage of mankind. And you are 100% right: even without Scriptures many a human learns truth of life through personal sufferings and experiences.

Yes, the internal knowledge that God has given man is important, but it may not be sufficient alone to fully discern truth from error, that is, it may be insufficient for a complete understanding of God's truth.  To do that it is important to listen to the teachings of the apostles.  (I John 4: 1-6)

@Joanne Yes, I agree, Homer's and Plato's writings aren't Bible, although they also are not infrequently conveying noble truth and correct insights.
